# how to extract version number form binary file using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I had tried to extract version number from a binary file.
The version number is after this string 'VeRsIoN_StRiNg'.
But how to find it using awk and print the next character I can't find out.

Someone ther can help?

/Lasse

Comment: Whose idea was it to "MySpAcE cAsE" a constant in production code?

Answer (score 2):

Do you strictly need to use awk? This seems like a better usecase for `grep --binary-files=text -o 'VeRsIoN_StRiNg.' file | grep -o '.$'`.

I'm not entirely sure how well a stream editor like awk will actually work with a binary file. If this is part of a larger awk script, you probably want to call the above grep formula from awk.

Comment: Obviously other utilities are available to extract the end of the selected text, `cut`, `awk`, and `sed` come to mind, but grep can also be used.

Comment: @Lasse: Welcome to StackOverflow. Around here "Thanks this was really easy :)" is best expressed as [a green tick next to the answer that helped you most](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

You can use strings command to find the printable strings in a object, or other binary, file

```sh
strings /path/to/binary | grep -o 'VeRsIoN_StRiNg.' | grep -o '.$'
```

Answer (score 0):

why not awk ?

```
gawk -b/mawk/mawk2 'BEGIN { RS = "^$"; FS = "^.*VeRsIoN_StRiNg" 

    } END { print substr($2,1,1)' # mawk/mawk2 or gawk in byte mode. 
                                  # LC_ALL=C gawk -e will be here too
```

even in gawk unicode mode, this workaround will do

```
gawk -e 'BEGIN { RS = "^$"; FS = "^.*VeRsIoN_StRiNg" 

    } END { printf("%.1s\n", $2) }' # gawk in unicode mode
```

This is to take advantage of the fact a "precision" N specified (e.g. %.ns) for %s means

**at most N** items printed

But since, by definition of `FS`, we *know* the first byte of `$2` is already your version number, a single character integer, then this printf will circumvent any gawk error message of complaining trying to do sub-strings on UTF8 non-compliant data.